# NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for AjaxDatatablesRails:Module- rails 4.2.11.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

My application is running on rails version 4.2.11.1. while using **gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', '~> 1.3.0'**, I got the below error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for AjaxDatatablesRails:Module
/home/vijay/ICANN/rails-atlarge/config/initializers/ajax_datatables_rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vijay/ICANN/rails-atlarge/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>
```

Now I have changed gem  version **gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', '~> 1.0.0'** then get bolow error.

```
uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions
22:44:00 worker.1 | /home/vijay/ICANN/rails-atlarge/app/datatables/admin/at_large_structures_datatable.rb:3:in `<class:AtLargeStructuresDatatable>'
22:44:00 worker.1 | /home/vijay/ICANN/rails-atlarge/app/datatables/admin/at_large_structures_datatable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>
```

Can anyone let me know for which version it will work fine or suggest me any other solutions.
Thanks